# Converting UTF-8 encoded with Latin-1 codepage to iso-8859-1 bytes

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

It's been a long day. I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something, or if there isn't an easy answer to my problem.

Here's my Scenario:

- I am sending text data as Bytes to a system that does not support UTF-8 encoding.
- It has a custom character set, but I only need characters that match the encoding of ISO-8859-1 / Latin-1.
- I have incoming UTF-8 encoded String data that only uses ASCII and a small number of foreign characters that are only from the Latin-1 code page.

In my attempts to re-encode these Strings, I end up with either '?' replacements for the foreign characters, the 2nd Unicode Byte, or both Unicode bytes being sent.

Is there a simple way to take this incoming data that uses 2 bytes to describe these Latin-1 code page characters and encode them as ISO-8859-1 Bytes?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the reader side you need something like:

```
new InputStreamReader(underlyingInputStream, "UTF-8")
```

On the writer side:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(underlyingOutputStream, "ISO-8859-1")
```

Then you should be able to read the incoming UTF-8 encoded characters, and write them as ISO-8859-1 encoded characters.